# What does "Little heart" mean?

Tags: meaning

Two bikers, Billy and Wyatt picks up a stranger on highway. Next, they rest by the
campfire:

> Billy: We're going to Mardi Gras.
>
> Stranger: **Little heart** is set on that, huh?
>
> Wyatt: We got a week. That's a week away, man.

What does "Little heart" mean?

Source: Easy Rider (1969)

Comment: Seems like a [patronising](https://www.lexico.com/definition/patronizing) tone.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am asking meaning of the word in given context.

Comment: It's probably just conversational deletion of "**Your** little heart..." if that helps.

Comment: [***My*** source](https://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search/sublanguageid-eng/idmovie-2106) (I just picked the first of a couple of dozen subtitle files at *opensubtitles.org*) has the relevant line transcribed as ***Your little heart is set on that, huh?*** I'm not going to try and find the corresponding audio, but I have no doubt the speaker makes at least *some* attempt to articulate the initial word ***Your*** there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it seems this text looks like it's trying to mimic real spoken conversation.

Real spoken conversation between individuals that know each other sometimes has a tendency to elide or omit the words at the beginning of sentences (conversational deletion as @stangdon mentions in comments), especially words that identify the subject.

The reason is both sides know who they are talking to and identifying you are talking to constantly sometimes indicates formality or distance.

So what's really being said is the below:

> Your little heart is set on that, huh?

This is not literally refering to the size of his primary circulatory organ.

*To set your heart on something* is an English idiom that means "to have a continued, focused desire or longing for getting, having, or doing something".

*Little* and equivalent expresses that refer to something has having a small size, is a common device used to express a patronizing tone as @WeatherVane said in the comments.

See the Wikipedia article for [diminutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive) for details on the concept as it relates to language in general.

Stranger is probably being patronizing because he feels the reason that Billy wants to go to Mardi Gras is childish, silly, or otherwise unnecessary.

Comment: 'His (or her) little heart is set on (something)' is often said of small children who want something very much.